# Cannot lazy load background image using Javascript LazySizes

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Trying to get lazysizes background images to lazyload.

reference: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Here are the details:

**Part 1: MY HTML**

```
<div class="imagebg">
    <div class="background-image-holder">
        <img alt="background" class="lazyload" src="/low-res.jpg" data-bg="/high-res.jpg" />
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Part 2: Javascript (in the footer of my site)**

```
<script src="/js/lazysizes.4.1.4.min.js" async=""></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('lazybeforeunveil', function(e){    
var bg = e.target.getAttribute('data-bg');    
if(bg){        
e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')';
    }
});
lazySizes.init();
</script>
```

Issue is the high-res image will not show at all. I'm sure this is a simple quick fix but I've tried everything.

Comment: Inspect the `background-image` property in chrome devtools and right-click on value, choose "open in new tab" and check if image shows up there.

Comment: Its showing the low-res image unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think it works but you can't see high res image as it is behind (in the background) of the low-res image. Either use both images as backgrounds or `<img>` sources so they can be replaced and not stacked on each other.

Comment: what I am not seeing is that using this library, if you inspect the image that is properly lazyloaded you will see that in the class...

properly lazyloaded:

    <img alt="Image" class="lazyloaded" src="low res" data-src="high-res">


not properly lazyloaded (what I see for background images)

    <img alt="Image" class="lazyload" src="low res" data-src="high-res">